# Postgres JSONb update (inside Json array), deletes all element in array when no match found or null parameter?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Given the following table:

```
create table documents(docu_id text, attachments jsonb);
insert into documents values
('001', 
    '[
      {"name": "uno","id":"1"},
      { "name": "dos","id":"2"},   
      { "name": "tres","id":"3"}
    ]'
),
('002', 
    '[
      { "name": "eins","id":"1"  },
      { "name": "zwei", "id":"2" }
    ]'
);
select * from documents;
```

[image]

I have this postgres query which works fine when I want to delete with an existing ID. But when I use a non existing id all items inside jsonarray attachments are deleted how to avoid this behavior?

```
UPDATE documents
   SET attachments = attachments #- /* #- Delete field/element with specified path */
   (
       '{' || /* Concat */ 
            (
            SELECT i
              FROM generate_series(0, jsonb_array_length(attachments) - 1) AS i
             WHERE (attachments->i->'id' = '"x"') /* <=====BUG origin */
           ) 
       || '}'
   )::text[] /* cast as text */
  where docu_id = '002';
```

Sample link with working data:
http://rextester.com/VZYSG74184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two simple queries that could to explain the problem source:

```
select '{' || (select 1 where false) || '}';
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
│ NULL     │
└──────────┘

with t(x) as (values('[1,2,3]'::jsonb))
select *, x #- '{1}', x #- '{}', x #- null from t;
┌───────────┬──────────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│     x     │ ?column? │ ?column?  │ ?column? │
├───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┤
│ [1, 2, 3] │ [1, 3]   │ [1, 2, 3] │ NULL     │
└───────────┴──────────┴───────────┴──────────┘
```

As you can see above when the parameter given is null with `#-` operator it deletes all content from json array.

It is simple to fix by constructing array in more convenient way:

```
UPDATE documents
   SET attachments = attachments #- /* #- Delete field/element with specified path */
   array(
            SELECT i
              FROM generate_series(0, jsonb_array_length(attachments) - 1) AS i
             WHERE (attachments->i->'id' = '"x"')
   )::text[] /* cast as text */
  where docu_id = '002';
```

test link: http://rextester.com/IIAS33106

Comment: thanks for explanation the with really makes it clearer. You solution works flawlessly!

Comment: So what is happening here is that you are creating an array type text with element found in the inner SELECt where 'id'='"x"', but in your first example with the `with` syntax I see you use Objects `{}` instead of array text[] .

Comment: @commonSenseCode In this case `{}` or `{1}` is not the object but [array notation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT). Actually in PostgreSQL string constants initially have type `unknown`: `select pg_typeof('foo');` and could be implicitly converted to the  particular type depending on situation. Because `#-` operator expecting `text[]` as its right operand then PostgreSQL interpreting "unknown" string constant as text array notation.

Comment: @commonSenseCode Please do not edit my answer if you not sure what you talking about :o) Operator `#-` does not "deletes all content". Most (probably all) of SQL operators returns `NULL` if any of its operand is `NULL`. `1 + NULL` returns null, `'a' || NULL` returns null, `NULL or true` also returns null etc. And `#-` is not exception but rule. Good luck!